# How to define an index structure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I want to create an LαP index in psotgresql, the definition of which is this:

[image: LαP inde structure]
1.Objects are first categorized into lattices according the number of incomplete values. For example, object D3 has only one field that has a value. So it's thrown into the lattice L[1].

2.In each lattice, objects are categorized into buckets according where the values are incomplete (the bitmap of incomplete value). For example, in L[3] there are two buckets. Object B1 is in bucket B<0111>, because only B1's first field is incomplete.

3.Objects in the same bucket are sorted by α, a column that is guaranteed not to be incomplete.

I know postgresql has two index: Gist and Gin, which supports extension. However, those two indexes are based on b-tree structure, and they take care of operations on the tree. What they allow to extend is to create a datatype or define operations for the datatype.

Now I want to change the structure of the index. Is there any interface for users to define their own index structure in postgresql? How can I create this LαP index?

Comment: Probably you should start with reading the source code and then ask on the postresql developer mailing list.

Comment: There's no user interface for creating new index types. Digging through the [commit history](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commits/master) for everything related to the new BRIN type will give you some idea of the work involved. Should be enough to scare you off...

Comment: In this particular case, you might be able to simulate the lattices / buckets via [table partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html), and use an ordinary B-tree index within each bucket.

Comment: @NickBarnes The real problem is sorting. I don't want to sort a bucket each time I use it. Table partitioning can simulate lattices/buckets, but it cannot maintain the order during updating or deleting entries.

Comment: @Kingston: A B-tree index on each bucket would maintain its order during updates and deletes, and would do so *much* more efficiently than a simple sorted list.

Comment: @NickBarnes Oh yes, It seems the only way I can build this LP index. Thank you.